how to get vite to compile scss/sass
I have a scss file i need compiled into a css file to be included on a blade template.
I have installed sass as a dependence.
I have the scss file listed in the scss additional data.
But during the build it does not output a css file for it.
The scss file is not imported into any javascript. This is legacy scss that was being built by gulp. I converting out gulp build into vite. the last item on my list is just to get it to output this scss->css.
This is my vite config
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import { viteStaticCopy } from 'vite-plugin-static-copy';
import path from 'path';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    viteStaticCopy({
      targets: [
        { src: 'resources/assets/images', dest: '' },
        { src: 'resources/assets/fonts', dest: '' },
        { src: 'node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts', dest: '' },
        { src: 'resources/assets/lib', dest: '' },
      ]
    })
  ],
  css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
      scss: {
        additionalData: `@import "resources/assets/sass/app.scss";` // Import your main SCSS file
      }
    }
  },
  publicDir: 'static',
  build: {
    outDir: 'public',
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        app: 'resources/assets/js/app.js',
        intake: 'resources/assets/js/intake/main.js',
        main: 'src/main.js'
      },
      output: {
        entryFileNames: 'js/[name].js',
        chunkFileNames: 'js/[name]-[hash].js',
        assetFileNames: 'css/[name]-[hash][extname]'
      }
    }
  },
  server: {
    port: Math.floor(3010 + Math.random() * (3999 - 3010))
  }
});

I have put it in the additionalData -> i expected it to output css
I imported it into the the app.js but then i get the error Error: This file is already being loaded.
